# Proving Lorentz Transformation identities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, mathematical-physics

> Given the defining property of Lorentz transformation (which is linear) $\eta_{\mu\nu}\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\rho}\Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\sigma} = \eta_{\rho \sigma}$, prove the following identities
>
> (i)      $$ (\Lambda k) \cdot (\Lambda x) = k \cdot x$$
>
> (ii)     $$ p \cdot (\Lambda x) = (\Lambda^{-1}p) \cdot x$$
>
> (iii)    $$ \left(\Lambda^{-1}k \right)^{2} = k^{2}$$

I understand that (i) can be proven as follows:

Given:

$$k' = \Lambda k, \ \ \text{where} \ \ k'^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\rho} k^{\rho}$$

And:

$$x' = \Lambda x, \ \ \text{where} \ \ x'^{\nu} = \Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}$$

Then:

$$k' \cdot x' = (\Lambda k) \cdot (\Lambda x) = \eta_{\mu \nu} k'^{\mu}x'^{\nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu}\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\rho}\Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\sigma}  k^{\rho} x^{\sigma} = \eta_{\rho \sigma} k^{\rho} x^{\sigma} = k \cdot x$$

---

My issue is proving (ii) and (iii) based on the same approach

- For (ii) I tried:

We now have

$$p' = \Lambda p, \ \ \text{where} \ \ p'^{\rho} = \Lambda^{\rho}{}_{\lambda} p^{\lambda}$$

$$x' = \Lambda x, \ \ \text{where} \ \ x'^{\nu} = \Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}$$

We need to solve for $p$

$$p^{\rho}= \Lambda_{\lambda}{}^\rho p^{'\lambda}$$

Thus

$$p \cdot x' = p \cdot (\Lambda x) = \eta_{\rho \nu} p^{\rho}x'^{\nu}=\eta_{\rho \nu} \Lambda_{\lambda}{}^\rho \Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\sigma} p^{'\lambda} x^{\sigma} =\Lambda_{\lambda}{}^\rho p^{'\lambda} x_{\rho} = (\Lambda^{-1} p') \cdot x$$

Note I simply assumed that $\Lambda_{\lambda}{}^\rho p^{'\lambda} x_{\rho} = (\Lambda^{-1} p') \cdot x$; how to prove such equation though?

- For (iii) I tried:

We now have

$$k' = \Lambda k, \ \ \text{where} \ \ k'^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\rho} k^{\rho}$$

We solve for $k$

$$k^{\mu}= \Lambda_{\rho}{}^\mu k^{'\rho}$$

Thus we get

$$k \cdot k = \eta_{\mu \nu} k^{\mu} k^{\nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} \Lambda_{\rho}{}^\mu \Lambda_{\sigma}{}^\nu k^{\rho}  k^{\sigma}$$

But here I do not see how to show that

$$\eta_{\mu \nu} \Lambda_{\rho}{}^\mu \Lambda_{\sigma}{}^\nu k^{\rho}  k^{\sigma} = (\Lambda^{-1} k)^2$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ii) is just $\Lambda \Lambda^{-1} p\cdot \Lambda x$ then apply i). Also, iii) follows from ii).

Comment: @JackyChong then $p \cdot x' =\eta_{\rho \nu} \Lambda_{\lambda}{}^\rho \Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\sigma} p^{'\lambda} x^{\sigma}$ is wrong?

Comment: @JackyChong but why is $k = \Lambda^{-1} p$?

Comment: It seems like $p = \Lambda k$ is just a definition. Where did you come across these questions?

Comment: @Physics_Et_Al Thanks for your comment. Exactly! I had to assume so in order to solve it. Please see #9 here https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/understanding-microcausality.989873/#post-6351722